# Parsley Custom Validator with JS Promise

Tags: javascript, flask, promise, parsley.js

I have reached out in several place and the help has been good but hasn't managed to make it work for me.

Hopefully you guys can help me here.

I am using JS inside a template page of a Flask application. I am using parsley validation to verify a web form. I have also created a custom validator which should ajax call with axios to the back end to determine if an email address is already registered.

My Flask Backend returns a boolean string to my html page. All of this looks right. I am getting back the right value. However when I return out of my ".then" function in my axios function the Parsley validator doesn't work/respond.

If i remove the axios POST call. and just simply say "return false" or "return true" the function works. The validation message is returned to the screen.

So there appears to be an issue with putting the return statment inside my .axios .then function?

Could some one see if I am doing anything wrong here? I cannot for the life of me work out why it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Tim.

I have included the FAILING JS Code here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.Parsley.addValidator('existingEmail', {
    validateString: function(value) {

        // Performing a POST request
        var promise = axios.post('/api/v1.0/existingEmailCheck', {email : value})
          .then(function(response){
            var result = (response.data.toLowerCase() === "true");
            console.log(result)
            return result
          });  

         console.log(promise)

         return promise

    },
    messages: {
        en: "This email address has already been registered.",
    }

});

</script>
```

I have also included a slightly modified (without axios call) code that works here.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.Parsley.addValidator('existingEmail', {
        validateString: function(value) {

            var string = "false" //This Simulates the Incoming Data.

            var result = (string.toLowerCase() === "true");
                console.log(result)
                return result   //Always returns false (due to hard coding)
                //However this means that it triggers the error message and validation fails
                //When you change the string to "true" it works as expected and validates
        },
        messages: {
            en: "This email address has already been registered.",
        }

    });

</script>
```

The example works as expected. Which leads me to believe the error in the first code example is somewhere between the call and the IF ELSE that returns the False or True

Any help people can give me would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Just attempted to use Axios myself (Wanted to do away with jQuery and it's huge library). Ended up creating a AsyncValidator (uses Ajax behind the scenes).

**In your HTML just import jQuery and Parsley**

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
```

**Define your DOM element to support remote validators**

```
<input id="id" class="form-control" name="id" type="text" data-parsley-remote data-parsley-remote-validator='checkExists' placeholder="Username / ID" data-parsley-checkExists="" data-parsley-minlength="5" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter username / id" required>
```

**In your `index.js` file, add you Async validator.**

```
 Parsley.addAsyncValidator('checkExists', function (xhr) {
    return false === xhr.responseJSON;
  }, '/data-management/verify-data?filter=signup');
```

The resulting Ajax request being made is `/data-management/verify-data?filter=signup&id=value` value being the value of the input field.

That ended up working for me. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return a jQuery promise instead of whatever `axios` returns (native promise?).

FWIW, it looks like you could use the builtin `remote` validator.